# HTTP 403 Forbidden with android kotlin and retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm working on sending data to an API and getting data back from it which is easy enough but how do i add api-key and client-id to my app (I'm using retrofit)? I tested it with Postman and it's working with both of them.

Comment: Not sure if "api-key" and "client-id" are GET request parameters, and/or POST headers/parameters, those details could help to answer, but all of it can be done with retrofit.

Comment: They can be added to GET request headers, tested them in postman. any idea where i could find an article or a stack overflow thread for how it can be added to retrofit?

Comment: https://square.github.io/retrofit/ shows you how

Comment: Found this for "android retrofit get header" search result - https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-add-custom-request-header

Comment: I checked every thread on stack overflow and didn't even cross my mind to check documentation, that was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed by simply adding `@Headers("key:value")` above the GET/POST api call.
[link to more info](http://square.github.io/retrofit)